# Android SDK - measure EMR (electromagnetic radiation)

Tags: android-sensors, android-sdk-tools

What is the best way to measure the **electromagnetic field** using the smartphone sensors?
Should I use the magnetometer? (**`TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD`**).
My aim is to measure the electromagnetic field generated by wi-fi networks, cordless phones, etc. (frequencies from about **800 to 2.2 GHz**).
I googled a lot but I don't found a valid answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no proper ways to measure electromagnetic (EM) field with smartphone sensors yet.

Since the field contains many components (Frequency, power, energy etc...).

Do you know exactly what do you want to measure?

In case of the energy the magnetometer could not measures the generated wi-fi and other radiommunications field, because of the difference of technology (lower frequencies in general)